# Out of range error when trying to find longest palindromic substring

Tags: string, data-structures

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [5. Longest Palindromic Substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/description/):

> Given a string `s`, return *the longest palindromic substring* in `s`.

This is my code:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        
        string res=""; //stores the result of longest palindrome substring
        int n=s.size();
        for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            int low=i;
            int high=i;

            while(s.at(low)==s.at(high))
            {
                low--;
                high++;

                if(low==-1 || high==s.length()  )
                break;
            }
            string str=s.substr(low,high);

            if(str.size()>res.size())
            res=str;

            low=i-1;
            high=i;
             while(s.at(low)==s.at(high))
            {
                low--;
                high++;

                if(low==-1 || high==s.length() )
                break;
            }
             str=s.substr(low,high);

            if(str.length()>res.length())
            res=str;

        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

I am getting this error:

> Runtime Error
> 0 / 141 testcases passed
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of `std::out_of_range`
> what():  `basic_string::substr`: __pos (which is 18446744073709551615) > `this->size()` (which is 5)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

- The inner `while` loops may exit when `i` is -1, but then just after the loop, you do: `s.substr(low,high)`, which triggers the error you got. -1 is not a valid argument here. Moreover, as the index `i` **never** indicates a character that belongs to the palindrome, you should actually *add* one to `lower` to get to the first character of the palindrome. To correct this bug, add `lower++;` just right after each inner `while` loop
- `substr` takes a *count* as second argument, not an index. So `s.substr(low,high)` doesn't do what you expect. It should be `s.substr(low,high-low)`
- When the input string is just one character, then your outer loop makes no iterations, and you will return the empty string. This is not correct, as obviously a single character is a palindrome. To fix this, initialise `res` to be the first character of the input string: `string res=s.substr(0, 1);` (note that it is given that the input string has at least one character)
- Not a bug, but it is good practice to indent your code properly. The statement that is subject to an `if` condition should be *indented*.

When these corrections are applied, it works:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        string res=s.substr(0, 1); // take the first character as a potential solution
        int n=s.size();
        for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            int low=i;
            int high=i;

            while(s.at(low)==s.at(high))
            {
                low--;
                high++;

                if(low==-1 || high==s.length())
                    break;
            }
            low++;  // let it reference the first character of the palindrome
            string str=s.substr(low,high-low); // Second argument must be a count
            
            if(str.size()>res.size())
                res=str;

            low=i-1;
            high=i;
            while(s.at(low)==s.at(high))
            {
                low--;
                high++;

                if(low==-1 || high==s.length())
                    break;
            }
            low++;  // same correction here as above
            str=s.substr(low,high-low);

            if(str.length()>res.length())
                res=str;

        }
        return res;
    }
};
```